# Using multiple models for collections in mongoDB mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im making a translation app, I want to have a new collection for each language.

When I go to /norwegian for instance I want to find from the collection of the same name.

How is this acheived?

at the moment I'm serving it like this.

```
// MONGOOSE/MODEL CONFIG
var norskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  english: String,
  phonetic: String,
  category: String,
  cat_id: Number,
  lang: String
}, {collection: 'norwegian'});

var Norsk = mongoose.model("norwegian", norskSchema);
```

then calling

```
app.get('/norwegian', function(req, res){
  Norsk.find(function(err, data) {
    res.render('index', {data: data});
  }).sort({ cat_id: 1});
});
```

Can I remove the collection object at the bottom of my schema and then call the same above adding a language as dot notation?

```
Trans.norwegian.find(function(err, data) {});
Trans.polish.find(function(err, data) {});
```

etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but you can programmatically get the model by its name using: `mongoose.model("norwegian")`

Comment: @JohnnyHK so instead of Norsk.find i would do mongoose.model("norwegian").find ?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JohnnyHK you can do something like the following:

```
app.get('/norwegian', function(req, res){
  mongoose.model('norwegian').find(function(err, data) {
    res.render('index', {data: data});
  }).sort({ cat_id: 1});
});
```

this should query with respect to a model without having to explicitly import the model .js object